# What is the practical difference between an neuromorphic processors and GPU's?

Tags: neural-networks

IBM is working on a neuromorphic computer, Synapse, intended for computation based on artificial neural networks.

My question is, what makes these types of computers more efficient at processing neural network algorithms, compared to GPU's?